# How to render a flat list in Angular with a nested array?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following data:

```
var days = [
  {
    events: [
      "e1",
      "e2"
    ]
  },
  {
    events: [
      "e3",
      "e4",
      "e5"
    ]
  }
  /* ... */    
];
```

(the real data has a lot more fields)

I need to render all events in one flat list:

```
<ul>
  <li>e1</li>
  <li>e2</li>
  <li>e3</li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do that without nesting the list by hand before the rendering? I tried with `ng-repeat` but won’t work over a nested array as I can’t nest elements in the rendering.

Comment: You can just merge the events into a new array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would handle it in the controller, like this:

```
$scope.getEvents = function () {
    var events = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.days.length; i++) {

        var currEvent = $scope.days[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < currEvent.events.length; j++) {    
            events.push(currEvent.events[j]);
        }
    }

    return events;
}
```

And then in HTML do like this:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="event in getEvents()">{{event}}</li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/11005/)

Comment: Isn't that the role of a service ?

Comment: @aduch You can do it in the service as well, in my applications I usually use core functionality that is intended for reuse in the services, and leave these sort of stuff like bundling for UI purposes in the controller.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I would do:

```
<ul>
  <dummy ng-repeat="day in days">
     <li ng-repeat="event in day.events">{{event}}</li>
  <dummy>
</ul>
```

Browser will ignore the dummy tag because it is custom and show only li tags.

It is not the perfect way to do it, but it will work for you

Comment: There is no universal rule for `dummy` is invalid tag. It's just a custom tag!

Comment: Browsers render invalid tags just like any other tag.

Comment: Corrected where I say it is an invalid tag. But the method I have used works. Without changing the javascript side and writing any methods to do it